# How to validate the response using schema validation in WSO2 API-M?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, json-schema-validator, wso2-micro-integrator

I need to validate the request in wso2 api-m then I need to forward the request to MI. I have done the validation using schema validation & also its working fine but while returning the 202 expected response back some message body is coming.

How to rectify this? I am new to api-m & schema validation.

Using WSO2 API-M 410.

Attached the expected response.
[image]

Expectation:

It should be like this
[image]

Comment: Where are you doing Schema validation and how? Is MI returning 202 response? What errors do you see in the logs?

Comment: @ycr I am doing validation in API-M with the help of schema validation. Yes MI returning 202. No errors in both the MI & APIM

Comment: Does it work when you call MI directly?

Comment: Yes, Even In API-M itself I am getting the response code but body only the issue. Dont know from where it is coming

Comment: This might be due to the Swagger definition being missing or malformed stating the Response flow of validation. Can you update the question with a sample Swagger definition that you are using to create the APIs? Also, do you see any errors in the wso2carbon logs when this behaviour is observed? If yes, please share them as well in the question to get more understanding of this behaviour.